# Wordpress duplicate pages according to WebMasterTools

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search-console

I checked my blog's performance on Google's Webmaster Tools, and under "Duplicate meta descriptions" I've got a lot of results with following format:

`/momart_blog/2012/09/25/5-odlicnih-primera-cenovnika-za-usluge-pricing-tables-design/`

`/momart_blog/2012/09/5-odlicnih-primera-cenovnika-za-usluge-pricing-tables-design/`

My permalinks are setup to show format `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`, so I don't know where from is this `/25/` is coming from, that represent the day article was written. Furthermore, why is Google indexing 2 articles, and how can I fix this? I have around 760 articles with this problem, and I'm scared Google would penalize my site.

Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [canonical meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) to avoid confusion.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/momart_blog/2012/09/5-odlicnih-primera-cenovnika-za-usluge-pricing-tables-design/" />
```

Did you recently update your permalink structure?
could be older pages in  googles index.

...or do you use XML sitemaps? if so, check the URLs provided in there.

Answer (score 0):

I will said that you had the structure including the day before. You could see from google when was indexed from cache and you will understand why.

From the google tools for webmasters you can delete a specific URL, I will recommend to delete this page and see if in the future is indexed again. (But I don´t think so)

I expect it will be helpful.